# Shopware6 What is the role of the DAL index in SW6?

Tags: shopware6

As far as I understand, Elastic Search can be used for the search functionality in SW6.

The console command es:index can be used to build up that index, and the data of the index itself will be stored in the Elastic Search cluster.

What I don't understand is the role of the DAL index also in conjunction with the
dal:refresh:index command.

Where does this Index store its data?
In what cases (for example) is this index used?

Comment: I found a video in the Shopware Online Academy which explains the matter quite well: [Indexing products and other entities](https://academy.shopware.com/courses/take/shopware-6-backend-development-with-jisse-reitsma/lessons/23393134-indexing-products-and-other-entities)